# How to update controller variable from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a date picker widget, and I want to pass the picked date to the controller. I have this script snippet in my view:

```
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
        $('#datepicker').datepicker()
        .on('changeDate', function(ev){

          alert(ev.date);
        });
        </script>
```

How to send this "ev.date" to the controller?

I want it to affect controller variable so this change is then picked up by a directive and dom is modified in the directive.

Comment: You can try using the angular event bus and fire an event.

Comment: This tells me nothing :( I only started with angularjs yesterday. Can you post an example on how to send data to a variable in controller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker()
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){
     //get a hold of controller and scope
     var element = angular.element($('#datepicker'));
     var controller = element.controller();
     var scope = element.scope();

     //as this happends outside of angular you probably have to notify angular of the change by wrapping your function call in $apply
     scope.$apply(function(){
       scope.updateDateFunction(ev.date);
     });
 });
```

See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: I have created an `updateDateFunction` definition in the controller: `$scope.updateDateFunction = function (date){
  $scope.pickedDate = date;
};` and used your code, unfortunately it does not work and gives the following error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'updateDateFunction'` The function is not misspelled.

Comment: You put the function on the $scope, not the controller (which is normal, I'll update my code to fit your structure)