# AngularJS scope variables not updating in jQuery promise/deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am building a single page application on `AngularJS` and I have a `controller` set up with a function that is run on a button click. This function runs with a promise. When the function is resolved I am updating a root variable and changing the `$location` path. But the root variable and `$location` dont seem to be updating.

> Please note this all code is exampled from production

DOM:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <button ng-click="button_function('I am a variable')">Run function</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

    $scope.button_function = function(variable) {
        $scope.$root.show_something = true;

        my_function.something(variable).done(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $scope.$root.show_something = false;
                $location.path('/go-to-path');
            } else {
                alert('Something went wrong');
            }
        }]);
    };

}]);
```

This is the `my_function` code:

```
var my_function = {
    something: function(variable) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        var window = window.open('http://dynamic.url/', '_blank');

        $(window).on('loadstart', function(e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.url;

            if (url === 'http://dynamic.url/expected_response') {
                window.close();
                deferred.resolve({
                    key_1: 'data',
                    key_2: 'more data'
                });
            }

        });

        return deferred.promise();
    }
};
```

All looks good right? But when the `my_function.something(variable)` is "done" the `$location` and `$scope.$root.show_something` don't seem to update.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update controller variable from jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886222/how-to-update-controller-variable-from-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the fix.

In my controller after the `deferred` is "done" I wrapped my variables in `$timeout`

```
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout', function($scope, $location, $timeout) {

    $scope.button_function = function(variable) {
        $scope.$root.show_something = true;

        my_function.something(variable).done(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.$root.show_something = false;
                    $location.path('/go-to-path');
                }, 1);
            } else {
                alert('Something went wrong');
            }
        }]);
    };

}]);
```

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784656/angularjs-location-not-changing-the-path/22843079#22843079)

Answer (score 0):

You should return `deferred.promise` instead of `deferred.promise()`.

--edit: my bad I didn't see you are not using $q as I misread.